# custom donation amount in stripe (php)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i am trying to make a donation page using stripe with a custom amount. the code works perfect with fixed amount,  but when i change it to variable amount it return 0, please help i tried many ways but nothing work. this is a snippet of the code

checkout.html

```
 <body>
    <section>

        <div class="panel">
          <h3>Donate Now</h3>
         <input type="number" id="amount" value="100"/>
        </div>
   

      <button type="button" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
    
    </section>
  </body>
    
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
    var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51J2BvHLTS6YsumlzTSoJwjdzJpMt5zUhcBcJo16SQnmOs1EJKLwW5CThE2qud0xMDZFq5q1b6ezNc29Q7Hc2nQaa00uAjNryX3");
      
    var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

    checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      fetch("create-checkout-session.php", {
        method: "POST", 
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
        body: JSON.stringify({amount: parseInt(parseInt(amount.value) * 100, 10),}),  
      
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (session) {
          return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          
          if (result.error) {
            alert(result.error.message);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

this is the php code:

create-checkout-session.php

```
    <?php

include'stripe-php/init.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxxxxxxx');

$DOMAIN = 'http://localhost/hro';

$content = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$amount = intval($content['amount']);

var_dump (file_get_contents('php://input'));

 $session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
          'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
          'line_items' => [[
            'price_data' => [
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'unit_amount' => $amount,
              'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'Your Donation Amount',
              ],
            ],
            'quantity' => 1,
          ]],
          'mode' => 'payment',
          'success_url' => $DOMAIN . '/success.html',
          'cancel_url' => $DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
        ]);

echo json_encode(['id' => $session->id]);
```

Comment: It looks like you're multiplying by 100 in both the frontend and backend code, but I think you only want to do so once, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, it is by mistake ..  even though it gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have multiple HTML elements on the page with an ID of `amount`?  If you run `console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value * 100, 10));` do you get the value you expect?

Comment: No, I have only one amount ID, and when I run `console.log(parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value * 100, 10));` I get the expected value

Comment: when I tried to log the data I got this error 'Error parsing JSON from response: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 5 Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost/hro/create-checkout-session.php", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}'

Comment: Have you removed all `echo` lines from `create-checkout-session.php` except the `echo json_encode(...` line?

Comment: yes I removed them.

Comment: If you log `file_get_contents('php://input')` on your server is it the JSON you expect?

Comment: No, ' file_get_contents('php://input') ' return null and 0 in the server

Comment: also when I tried to log the '$session->id ' I got null

Comment: Is `$session` supposed to be `$checkout_session` instead?  Can you update your question with the current code you're using?

Comment: Thanks alot for your replays ... I updated the code.

Comment: after updating the code it logs the payment in my stripe account as a successful payment, however  it didn't redirect my to the create-checkout-session.php and it gave me this error `Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0` .

Comment: What steps lead to that error and where exactly are you seeing it?  If you remove or comment out the `var_dump (file_get_contents('php://input'));` line does that fix it?

Comment: I think the error is from the js code .. but I don't know why . I used another integration from stripe ,it used only html and php and it works well.  thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` returned by `amount.value` is of string type, so you can't multiply it just like that. You need to `parseInt` the `amount.value` first, and then do the multiplication outside the `parseInt`.

```js
amount: parseInt(parseInt(amount.value) * 100, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay .. I made the changes as you say but still gives the same 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS Code looks good but: Please check the type of amount on the server side. Because this will be a string. Then you have to cast it to an int.
`intval($amount)`

Comment: I already did that `$amount = intval($content['amount']); ` .